# Как на python объединить строку кода

Tags: python

Пример:

```
print("текст")
print("текст")
print("текст")
n=int(input("текст 1 или 2")
if n == 1:
        print("текст")
if n ==2:
        print("текст")
```

как сделать что бы он был как единое целое?:D
Например как:

```
n=print("текст")
```

Теперь print имеет значение. Типо такова:D

Comment: Ничего не понял...

Comment: Как сделать что бы строка кода имела прив'язку к чему то, например как n = print.

Comment: Привязку к чему чему-то? Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: Всё ещё ничего не понял... О какой привязке речь? Функция `print` ничего не возвращает, поэтому в такой ситуации значение `n` будет всегда равно `None`

Comment: Например, я хочу что бы kod = [print("текст") потом ещё код vubor =int(input("текст 1 или 2") потом выбор if vubor == 1: текст if vubor == 2: print("текст")]. И вот это все должно быть привязано к чему то, например к kod. В скобках от начала до конца кода.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "привязано"? Что-то тут без Jack Daniels не разберешься...

Comment: Что бы его можно было использовать, например в. random.choice([kod, htoto ehe]): и когда рандом выдаёт kod появлялся этот код

Comment: Если правильно вас понял, оберните весь нужный код в функцию, положите имя функции список, потом через random.choice выбираете случайную функцию и вызываете ее добавив скобки ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно вас понял, то `что бы он был как единое целое`, `Что бы его можно было использовать, например в. random.choice([kod, htoto ehe]): и когда рандом выдаёт kod появлялся этот код` - это про функции. Т.е. оборачиваем код в функцию, например:

```
def func1():
    print("Функция 1")


def func2():
    print("Функция 2")


random_func = random.choice([func1, func2])

random_func()  # выполнится одна из двух функций, которую выберет random.choice
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое. Все работает!:)

Comment: Ну так, может, просто `print(random.choice(["текст 1", "текст 2"]))`?

Comment: @КириллМалышев, если просто одиночный принт, то можно и так, если же "что бы он (код) был как единое целое", то через функции)

Comment: Тогда так https://stackoverflow.com/a/3188134/7485582